# How should I build up stair stringers (instead of cutting them out)?

Tags: stairs

I'm thinking of building a stair stringer using a 2x6 and reclaimed wood triangles.

How to fix the triangles on the base, long screws, nails?

[image][image: Two parts stair stringer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastening the wood triangles to the 2x6 can be done in a number of ways such as glue and dowel rods as suggested in another answer. The addition of a plywood scab on the side as suggested in a comment is even better.

But also consider that as drawn in your picture the construction of a stairway with triangles cut at 45 degrees would produce a stairway with narrow steep steps such as you might find in some house built 120 years ago. Modern stairways are built with the rise of each step less than the run of each step. If you were cutting your triangles out of reclaimed 2x6's (which are 5.5 inches wide) you would want to cut them more like the right hand side of the below picture.

[image]

The angles and dimensions as shown to the right above are only an example and may very well not be exactly correct for your application or even within the range of code standards for stairs. Keep in mind that the design of a stairway requires careful calculations, taking tread thickness and flooring thickness at the head and base of the stairs into account so that all the steps are a uniform size. Uniformity is important for building code compliance and safe usage of the stairway.

Answer (score 2):

Our wood working site might have some good ideas.

If I was doing this, I'd be gluing the triangles to the 2x6  and then use dowel rods, one vertical and one horizontal, for additional support. You could also use screws depending on how you wanted to finish the stairs. Since you're reclaiming the triangles, the dowel rods might be more appropriate.

Comment: I'd scab some plywood to the sides overlapping, plus glue and screws. Stairs take a lot of loading.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Dowel rods or dowel pins.... come on, It's Sunday and we lost an hour of sleep... lol  The dowel rods can be cut longer than most packaged dowel pins.

Comment: @Jack It is good idea from you, but would you consider place short, well fitted, dowels across the contact plane of the step board and the stringer, then glue them together.

Comment: @r13  That would work great and be stronger. You'd probably need a dowel hole drilling guide tool, but could use smaller dowel pins.

Answer (score 2):

Your plan isn't safe and may even cost more than the typical method of cutting stair stringers from larger dimensional lumber, e.g. a 2x12.

I recommend you check your local library for the book [Building Stairs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LTYC3C4) by Andy Engel.  This will tell you everything you need to know about planning, framing, and finishing your staircase -- including the correct way to make stringers safely.

If you insist on your *nailed triangles plan* I encourage you to contact your local building official for guidance before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks! But some hardware stores sell stringers as I illustrated. I added a photo to the question.

Comment: Hardware store stringers are bound to disappoint about 95% of the time because they don't take your particular rise into account. You'll end up with one or two chopped steps, which is usually sub code, and tricky to navigate. Cutting real stringers from lumber is better (less to fail), and just as easy (if not easier) as using triangles.While the benefit of free reclaimed lumber is obvious, the downside of having crappy stairs would seem to offset that.